# NGINX and PHP Gzip compression not working in browser but works in cURL

Tags: php, nginx, compression, gzip

There is a peculiar issue happening in my NGinx and PHP Setup.

My Test URL : http://104.194.26.13:2002/a.php

I am using PHP with NGinx (FCGI). To compress the data I am using :

```
<?php

ob_start('ob_gzhandler');

phpinfo();

?>
```

When accessed via the browser it shows :

```
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

But there is no Content-Encoding and the size of the downloaded data shown in Firebug is that of a non-compressed data.

When accessed from CLI using curl :

```
curl -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" "http://104.194.26.13:2002/a.php"
```

There are some gbiresh characters suggesting it did encode. If you save the output with the above command the size is 17.5 KB instead of the 75 KB when accessed via the browser.

Here is the full headers received from my a.php file :

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 75550
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Fri, 15 Jan 2016 05:37:43 GMT
Server: nginx
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.27
```

What could be possibly wrong ?

Comment: why are you handling the compression at `php` side and not in the `nginx` config?

Comment: For my application I cant use gzip at the nginx layer.

Answer (score 0):

Which browser are you using, because Chrome `47.0.2526.106 m` shows this:

[image: request]

Now, as stated in the comments, why don't you try and compress it directly from Nginx? By leveraging gzip compression within the nginx config:

```
# enable gzip compression
gzip on;
gzip_min_length  1100;
gzip_buffers  4 32k;
gzip_types    text/plain application/x-javascript text/xml text/css;
gzip_vary on;
# end gzip configuration
```

<sup>[*Source*](https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/how-to-configure-nginx-gzip-compression/)</sup>

---

Here are my request headers:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:104.194.26.13:2002
Referer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34805168/nginx-and-php-gzip-compression-not-working-in-browser-but-works-in-curl/34805312?noredirect=1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: I am using Firefox 43.0.4 with Firebug. At this point in time I cant use nginx gzip for my application. Strangely even in my chrome its not showing your result : `Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:75821
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Fri, 15 Jan 2016 06:31:44 GMT
Server:nginx
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.27`

Comment: Also the utility at : http://www.giftofspeed.com/gzip-test/ confirms its not working.

Comment: Hrm that's weird, I'm getting the exact same results Firefox `41.0.1`, ps, do you have the `zlib` extension loaded? As `ob_gzhandler` requires it.

Comment: Yes. Its loaded. If you see the output of the file its a phpinfo() dump. It shows zlib is loaded and also registered as a stream.

Comment: That is super weird, why don't you give the `nginx` configuration a shot?

Comment: For curiosity I did try the nginx conf and turned of ob_gzhandler. I still get the same results. Can you post your request headers ? Here are mine : `Accept 
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate
Accept-Language 
en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection 
keep-alive
Host 
104.194.26.13:2002
User-Agent 
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0`

Comment: @user1066991 sure thing, I'll add to my post